# Ios Flutter, App asks for sign in on launch

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I was working on firebase messaging today for my flutter app and I followed several steps [for ios version here.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/) My app keeps on asking me for Apple ID and password whenever I launch the app on iOS simulator. If i press cancel or leave and reopen the app it forces me to enter these information or it wont let me use the app. Even if I enter these informations, it just asks me again on the next launch. I am a total beginner in iOS and I have no idea whats going on. I signed the app and created provisions. Maybe these things made this happen.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Everytime when app launches ask me for sign in. LOL ? Any workaround on this?

Comment: This will be very strange to tell but what I did is, type username as "Adidas" and password something random, it will pop a dialog, on the dialog choose to go to the settings, on the settings click on top left where your app name is and it will not bother you. I dunno what is going on but I found this stupid workaround

Comment: Yes, very strange hahha I will try it. But, this problem (ask sign in with apple) do appears on real devices? It will be a problem (because users will not do this strange thing). Did you tested it on real devices on prod version?

Comment: In real devices this doesn't occur. I dunno why but this seems to be a simulator issue

Comment: Thanks. I will try to publish and prod version to real devices and see what happens :)

Comment: This error sucks... If your first screen is a splash and have an logic that waits a few seconds, the screen dies (when the dialog appears) and don't continue... I've closed the dialog as you told going to settings and back, but when the dialog should be appears (and it does not appearing now) the screen freezes... lol Idk what to do ;(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this guys?